# Hex-encode ISO-8859-1 characters (outside of ASCII) in string?

Tags: php, string, hex, iso-8859-1

eg. input:

```
Riferimento-a-â‚¬-9-90
```

output:

```
Riferimento-a-%E2%82%AC-9-90
```

please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is your question? Help with what? Input or output? Explanation what happens here? If it is safe to use? And please add your code. The input string does not look like ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 3):

To convert the ISO-8859-1 string to triplet / percentage encoding, use [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode):

```
$encoded = rawurlencode($str);
```

However, the string you have pasted into the question is not ISO-8859-1 encoded, if it would contain the `BPH` (Break Permitted Here) control character which is a non-printable character. Like the triplet/hex-encoded string, the following PHP notation is binary safe as well:

```
$str = "Riferimento-a-\xE2\x82\xAC-9-90";
```

Taking that as an UTF-8 encoded string, results in the following:

```
Riferimento-a-€-9-90
```

`%E2%82%AC` is the urlencoded UTF-8 encoding of EURO SIGN (U+20AC).

Which is probably what you're looking for.

Loosely related: [How to substitute non SGML characters in String using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737335/367456)

---

You asked additionally in comments:

> How to convert `&egrave;` to `%hex` ?

As there is no `&egrave;` (`è`) involved, I guess you're not really clear about what you ask here. But I start with what you ask first, because it's most simple. It's a two-step process:

[image: render?grid=%2B--------%2B+++%2B--------%2B---------%2B+++%2B-----%2B------%2B+++%2B---%2B----%2B%0D%0A%7C+cFDA+++%7C+++%7C+Decode+++++++++++%7C+++%7C+Encode+++++%7C+++%7C+cFDA+++%7C%0D%0A%7C+Entity+%2B--%3E%2B------------------%2B--%3E%2B------------%2B--%3E%2B+Entity+%7C%0D%0A%7C+%26Name%3B+%7C+++%7Chtml_entity_decode%7C+++%7Crawurlencode%7C+++%7C+%25HEX+++%7C%0D%0A%7C+++++%7Bd%7D%7C+++%7C++cDBF++++++++++++%7C+++%7C++c1AB++++++%7C+++%7C+++++%7Bd%7D%7C%0D%0A%2B--------%2B+++%2B--------%2B---------%2B+++%2B-----%2B------%2B+++%2B--------%2B&scale=1&background=FFFFFF&E=on&timeout=10]

You first convert the named HTML entity into a standard character in your target character encoding:

```
$entity = '&egrave;';
$iso_8859_1 = html_entity_decode($entity, NULL, 'ISO-8859-1');
```

Then you convert it to the ´%hex` encoding which is more commonly called urlencoding:

```
$hex = rawurlencode($iso_8859_1);
```

And that's it basically. If you try to convert an entity that does not exists in the target encoding, then it's not converted so the information is preserved regardless of the character encoding.

However I assume that's only informative for you, because you have some other problems than just running these conversions.

> In phpmyadmin, it display as `"Riferimento-a-â‚¬-9-90"`, I want to convert it to `"Riferimento-a-%E2%82%AC-9-90"`

You have not shared how that what is displayed is actually textually represented, but because you asked about named HTML entities (e.g. `&egrave;`) I assume you're concerned about the `â‚¬ / %E2%82%A` part specifically:

```
â    %E2    Windows-1252    LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX (U+00E2)
‚    %82    Windows-1252    SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK (U+201A)
¬    %AC    Windows-1252    NOT SIGN (U+00AC)
```

The information you've been given about ISO-8859-1 for those characters is wrong, because in ISO-8859-1 `‚ / %82` does not exist, at that place is some C1 set control code. So I assume that it's `Windows-1252` which is [common in HTML documents](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#character-encodings-0).

As you wrote that you recieve your data from the database, I assume that phpmyadmin displays the UTF-8 text you've got in your database as Windows-1252:

```
MySQL      : UTF-8:         \xE2\x82\xAC (€)    
PHPMyAdmin : Windows-1252:  \xE2\x82\xAC (â‚¬)
```

If you now get UTF-8 encoded data from your database, you only need to run `rawurlencode` on it to get the hexencoding your ask for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I use rawurlencode to convert "Riferimento-a-â‚¬-9-90", I get "Riferimento-a-%C3%A2%E2%80%9A%C2%AC-9-90", not "Riferimento-a-%E2%82%AC-9-90", which was what I want, could you tell me how to get the correct characters? I am Asian, not familiar with european characters handling, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: and how to convert &egrave; to %hex mode? is their any build-in function can do this, or i have to build a mapping array to convert them all

Comment: this string comes from mysql database, with phpmyadmin, it display as "Riferimento-a-â‚¬-9-90", i want to convert it to "Riferimento-a-%E2%82%AC-9-90".