# How use Scrapy encodage

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, utf-8, scrapy

I'm blocked with encodage issue when using Scrapy, hope someone can help me.

- On my spider : `item['title'] = html.xpath('.//h5/text()')`
- On pipeline : `item['title'] = item['title'].extract()[0].encode('utf-8', 'replace')`

It result string like `Namontana \xe2\x80\x93 Une attaque \xc3\xa0 main arm\xc3\xa9e avort\xc3\xa9e`. I save all item on database (mysql for now).

Now I want to show all this items to a website but my problem is I can't transform **\xe2** (for example) to visual char.

I've already try :

- Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at begin of all .py file
- Use `htmlentities` or `utf8_decode` functions when display with PHP code
- Add `unicode(response.body.decode(response.encoding)).encode('utf-8')` on my spider
- Add `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` to my HTML page
- Check and convert all file to UTF8 without BOM

For now, my only alternative is to use custom function to replace all char (explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736949/how-to-substitute-non-sgml-characters-in-string-using-php)) but I thinks they've better solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

On every file (spiders, pipelines, etc..) and convert (on pipeline) string from unicode to utf8 [.encode( 'utf-8', 'replace' )]

Answer (score 0):

e28093 is hex for the utf8 encoding for an EN DASH: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm

c3a0 and c3a9 represent accented letters:

```
mysql> SELECT UNHEX('e28093c3a0c3a9');
+-------------------------+
| UNHEX('e28093c3a0c3a9') |
+-------------------------+
| –àé                     |
+-------------------------+
```

I don't know what is providing the "\x", but that is a common leadin for hex.

If a SELECT comes up with \x, etc, then that is not a good way to store the data.  If `SELECT HEX(column)` comes up with `...e28093...`, then that is good.

Answer (score 0):

Problem come from my DB encoding. Now it's utf8_unicode_ci and it's works great.